# git merge-file dry-run / Detect if 2 files with a common ancestor file can be merged with automatic conflict resolution

Tags: git, git-merge

We have a git mergedriver that has grown over the years and until now it worked fine.

Now we need to check if the merge conflict could be merged by Git automatically before doing anything else.

The problem is, git merge-file provides it's output in one of the input files.

Is there a read only way to check wether 2 files can be merged by Git automatically besides copy & pasting the files somewhere else? I couldn't find any dry-run option or something similar.

Comment: "Copy-pasting" files is trivial in a script: `cp file /tmp/file` and then run `git merge-file` on `/tmp/file`. You're going to want this to be scripted anyway, so why not do it now?

Comment: @matt no it does not as this is related to a merge driver, so you have not branches to merge, you only have 3 files (common, current and other).

Comment: @torek of course this would do the trick but IMHO a merge driver should "mess up" the workspace as little as possible even if he cleans up after itself, that's why I'm looking for a maybe better solution.